# Not IN() Innaccuracy

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to view a list of zip codes that are in list1 but not in list2 so that I can see which area was hit with which mailing (1st or 2nd).  I have tried the below query but it is returning 0 records, and after a manual line by line I found at least 80 zips that were in list1 but not in list2.  What is the issue with my query that caused the zips to not be returned as not in()

```
Select marketingtype, zip As [Area Marketed]
From campaignDB.list1
WHERE marketingtype Is Not Null
AND zip NOT IN (Select zip from campaignDB.list2)
Order By zip ASC
```

Comment: was marketingtype null by any chance for those 80 zips?

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev no, marketing type was not null.  Marketing type had a value for all records in campaignDB.list1

Comment: Are there any `NULL` zips?  I'd exclude NULL zips:  `(Select zip from campaignDB.list2 WHERE zip IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select marketingtype, A.zip As [Area Marketed]
From campaignDB.list1 A
LEFT JOIN campaignDB.list2 B on A.zip = B.zip
WHERE B.zip IS NULL 
and marketingtype IS NOT NULL
Order By zip ASC
```

Comment: Left join could have worked, but as @DMason mentioned above you would have had  to exclude the NULL columns.